# Scala admin framework to build a simple CRUD application?

Tags: scala, frameworks, admin

We need to build a simple CRUD application for admins.

Is there any admin framework for scala, similar to ruby's `ActiveAdmin`?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Skinny Framework](http://skinny-framework.org/documentation/scaffolding.html), the scaffolding feature should help.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveAdmin` is a RoR plugin and not a Ruby library. and no, there is no equivalent Scala lib.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?